# Как подключиться к C# серверу, используя мобильный интернет - Android, C#

Tags: java, android, c#, nat

Здравствуйте! Делаю проект, он состоит из сервера на C#, клиента на C#, клиента Android Java. Проблема в следующем: мне не удается подключиться к серверу на C#.

Информация:

1. Есть роутер ZyXEL Keenetic II
2. Порты пробрасываю на роутер. Библиотека: [NAT Traversal with UPnP in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27992/NAT-Traversal-with-UPnP-in-C). Из этой же библиотеки беру внешний ip адрес и все подключения по этому адресу (даже в локальной сети)
3. Интернет провайдер: ТТК (доступ в Интернет есть, также ip адрес статический)
4. Мобильный оператор: Билайн. Безлимитный интернет (доступ в Интернет есть)
5. Код сервера (проброска портов):

   ```
   var discoverer = new NatDiscoverer();
   var device = await discoverer.DiscoverDeviceAsync();
   await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 1406, 1406, "RemoteTech"));
   Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Your external ip: {1}",
               DateTime.Now.ToString(culture), await device.GetExternalIPAsync());
   ```
6. Код сервера (принятие подключений, делал по примеру из MSDN (примеры асинхронных сокетов сервера), не могу добавить больше 1-ой ссылки):

   ```
      // Thread signal.
      public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
      // ....
      //....
   // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
       IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 1406);

       // Create a TCP/IP socket.
       Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
           SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

       // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
       try
       {
           listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
           listener.Listen(100);

           while (true)
           {
               // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
               allDone.Reset();

               listener.BeginAccept(
                   new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                   listener);

               // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
               allDone.WaitOne();
           }

       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Error: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(culture), e.Message);
       }
   ```

активное подключение добавляется в массив

7. Код подключения клиента C# к серверу (не буду выкладывать, т.к. он точь-в-точь как на MSDN (примеры асинхронных сокетов клиента))
8. Код подключения клиента Android Java к серверу (также пробовал другие библиотеки, но эффект тот же, и остановился на сокетах, т.к. пробовал последним вариантом):

   ```
   do {
           socket = GetSocket(); // Создание соединения
       } while (socket == null); // Пытаемся создать подключение
   //....
   @Nullable
   private Socket GetSocket(){
   try {
       // Установка соединения (timeout = 3000 ms)
       Socket setSocket = new Socket();
       setSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(MainConnection.SERVER,
               MainConnection.PORT), 3000);
       return setSocket;
   }
   catch (Exception ex){
       Log.e(getClass().getName(),
               "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
   }
   return null;
   }
   ```

8.5. Все разрешения в манифесте указал:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

9. В локальной сети всё работает отлично, но вот по Интернету клиент C# подключается (даже отправлял другу, который живет в другом городе, чтобы протестировать), а клиент на Android никак.
10. Также ошибка, которую выдает андроид в LogCat (где пишет "Software caused connection abort" это момент, когда я подключаюсь к локальной сети):

    ```
    05-26 20:03:15.505 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: connect timed out
    05-26 20:03:18.522 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: connect timed out
    05-26 20:03:21.535 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: connect timed out
    05-26 20:03:22.774 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Software caused connection abort
    05-26 20:03:22.777 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.779 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.782 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.784 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.792 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.796 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.800 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.805 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.808 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.810 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.812 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.813 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.815 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.823 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.827 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.851 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Error: Network is unreachable
    05-26 20:03:22.858 26882-26927/com.hfad.remotetech E/com.hfad.remotetech.SocketClient: Connection established
    ```

PS: Если нужна еще какая-то информация пишите

Comment: На будущее: вместо того чтобы делать BeginAccept, а потом ждать - можно сделать простой Accept, результат будет такой же.

Comment: Андроид как в интернет выходит? Не может просто оператор связи трафик резать?

Comment: И да, не хватает кода на андроиде.

Comment: Тестишь на каком андроиде? С зефирки ввели разрешения в рантайме, в манифесте теперь пишут для поддержки леденца и ниже

Comment: Тест провожу на Samsung A5 2016 (версия android 7.0)

Comment: А какой код еще нужен? Я написал основной код подключения к серверу.